# How can I access an ArrayList that was created within an 'if' statement?

Tags: java, if-statement, arraylist, scope

Could someone please help me, im trying to use the arraylist called prop outside the if statement where it was declared and where I added an object to it.

Here is the if statement.  The code asks the user to input info, then a Property object and an ArrayList of properties are declared where it adds the property object I created into the ArrayList.

```
if(option.equals("one")){

    int x = 1;
    do{
        try{
            System.out.println("Enter owner name");
            String ownerName = scan.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter address");
            String address = scan.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Are you the principle private residant?");
            String principlePrivateResidance = scan.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter property location(city, large town, small town, vilage, countryside) ");
            String location = scan.nextLine();
            System.out.println("would you like to pay the propery tax now?(yes//no)");
            String paid = scan.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter your filename");
            String fn = scan.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter the estimated property value");

            int propertyEstimatedVal = scan.nextInt();
            // i make the object here 
            Property property = new Property(ownerName, address, paid, principlePrivateResidance,location, propertyEstimatedVal);

            // Then make the arraylist and add the object to it take this arraylist and put it....

            ArrayList<Property> prop = new ArrayList<Property>;
            prop.add(property);
            CalculateTax tax = new CalculateTax(property.getLocation(),property.getPrinciplePrivateResidance(),property.getPropertyEstimatedVal(), property.getPaid());

            System.out.println("owner:" + property.getOwnerName());
            System.out.println("address:" +property.getAddress());
            System.out.println("propertyEstimatedVal:" +property.getPropertyEstimatedVal());
            System.out.println("principlePrivateResidance:" +property.getPrinciplePrivateResidance());
            System.out.println("location:" +property.getLocation());
            System.out.println("paid:" +property.getPaid());
            System.out.println("Your property tax is" + CalculateTax.getSumoftax() );
            System.out.println("your details have been taken");

            FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter(fn,true);
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
            out.write(property.getOwnerName() + " | " + property.getAddress() + " | " + property.getPropertyEstimatedVal() + " | " + property.getPrinciplePrivateResidance() + " | " + property.getLocation() + " | " + property.getPaid() + " | " + CalculateTax.getSumoftax());
            out.newLine();
            out.close();
            x= 2;
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("error has occured");
        }
    }
    while(x == 1);

}
else if(option.equals("two")){
    // this just opens a file
    System.out.println("Please enter you file name");
    String filename = scan.nextLine();

    try{
        // Open the file that is the first
        // command line parameter
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(filename);
        // Get the object of DataInputStream
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String strLine;

        //Read File Line By Line
        while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
            // Print the content on the console
            System.out.println (strLine);
        }
        //Close the input stream
        in.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e){//Catch exception if any
        System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
else if(option.equals("three")){
    //i need to get that arraylist with the objects i added to it here but
    //i just dont know how
    System.out.print("Service is currently available ");

}
else{
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. Please edit it to clarify the exact problem you have.

Comment: You need to declare your variable in a high enough scope that it is visible to all the parts of your class where its needed. This normally implies declaring it as a class variable, but it could also be that you just need to declare the variable at the top of your method. As it is your code is very hard to read, so I cant say definitely where you need to place the variable. Please format and repost.

Comment: One of your branches creates the ArrayList and the other one tries to access it — how is that possible? The code looks like you *either* create the list *or* use it.

Comment: sry about the messyness i spent half an hour trying to post it, i need to use the arraylist and the object i add to it outside the if statement its in

Comment: supposed to be ArrayList<Property> prop = new ArrayList<Property>;

Comment: Voted to close as 'too localised', which is also the answer to the question.

Answer (score 2):

You need to move your array list decalration/insntantiation outside your `if` statement as below:

```
        List<Property> prop = new ArrayList<Property>;

        if(option.equals("one")){
             //your if block code
            do{
               //rest of your code except list declaration/initialization
              }while(x==1);
              ....
        }else if(option.equals("two")){
           .....
        } else if(option.equals("three")){
           //your list `prop` is available here
           ....
        }
```

This is required for two reasons:

1. Currently you are re-instantiating the prop list in each iteration of your `do-while` loop and loosing the previously added data.
2. Your list is in scope of the `if` block only while you need to access it outside of `if` i.e. in else block.

By moving the list initialization outside `if` block, you will fix both of the issues.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to access the `ArrayList` outside of the `if` statement, you need to move the variable declaration to happen before the `if` statement. For example, remove the line here...

```
Property property = new Property(ownerName, address, paid, principlePrivateResidance,location, propertyEstimatedVal);

// Then make the arraylist and add the object to it take this arraylist and put it....

ArrayList<Property> prop = new ArrayList<Property>; // REMOVE THIS LINE
prop.add(property);
```

And add it here instead...

```
ArrayList<Property> prop = new ArrayList<Property>; // ADD THIS LINE

if(option.equals("one")){

    int x = 1;
    do{
```

Now the `ArrayList` is defined before your `if` statement, so you can use it anywhere inside and outside of the `if` statement.

You would probably want to move your `ArrayList` outside your `do-while` loop anyway, otherwise a new `ArrayList` will be created each time you go through the `do-while` loop. I'm sure what you actually want is to create a single `ArrayList` and just add a number of items to it - therefore you need to move the declaration of the `ArrayList` outside the `do-while` loop, which is also achieved by my code change above.

The next thing you'll need to do is to detect whether an item was added to your `ArrayList` or not. If you don't execute the code in your `if(option.equals("one")){` statement, nothing will be added to the `ArrayList`, so it will be empty. Therefore, if you want to use your `ArrayList` later, you should first check whether there are any items in it, and then use them if they exist - maybe something like this...

```
if (prop.size() > 0){
    // there are items
    doSomething();
}
else {
    // no items
    doSomethingElse();
}
```